# handling class name with spaces in it html

Tags: html, css

I have a joomla ice accordion on a website. I am trying to get the links of the accordion tabs by using Firebug

The code for one of the tabs is

```
<p id="ABC" class="msg_head">Content</p>
```

The link to this tab is

```
https://website.org/eweb/DynamicPage.aspx?Site=Inst&WebKey=81c17c83-4cb1-456a-a9d5-6b8fcc94fc63&accordion=EMD#EMD
```

What do I put the link of the following as?

```
<p id="ABC sub" class="msg_head">Content</p>
```

Comment: id="ABC sub" is an invalid ID and generally your browser will probably see it as id='ABC' and give you a property called sub. In short DON'T.

Comment: Also I think you have the concepts of class and ID mixed up. Id's are unique and contain no spaces. Classes also contain no spaces but are not unique and you can have multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're looking to put the value "ABC sub" in the query string. So you'll have "Accordion=ABC sub".

You'll want to URL encode, so spaces will equal "%20" according to:[URL Encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

"Accordion=ABC%20sub"

Comment: @user1212 Try `Accordion=ABC+sub#ABC%20sub`