# handling css id and classes with spaces

Tags: css

I have a paragraph as

```
<p id="para one" class="paragraph one">Content</p>
```

How does one represent the id and class with spaces in the css

When I use

```
#para#one{
}

.paragraph.one{
}
```

It does not work with the css above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [handling class name with spaces in it html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284313/handling-class-name-with-spaces-in-it-html) by the same user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
class="paragraph one"
```

actually represents two different classes

```
id="para one"
```

won't work, but you'll probably end up having an actual id of para

Comment: If you have no control over these white spaced IDs, you can still target them like this:

`#para\ one`

or by doing a substring match

`[id*='para']`

Answer (score 61):

Just came across this one myself (styling an existing page with no way to change the id).

This is what I used to style it by id:

```
p[id='para one']{
}
```

And, as said previously, `.paragraph.one` selects two classes - this means it will also select elements with `class=" one paragraph"` and `class="not a paragraph this one"`.

Comment: Not sure why the answer by Mikey G was selected as correct. The suggestion here worked absolutely fine to hide a compliciated class name in a wordpress widget.

Comment: Upvoted, best answer, works well in Tampermonkey too.

Comment: you don't even need the "p", could just use [id='para one']{}

Answer (score 30):

Your class CSS is correct. You don't have a class with a space in it, you have two classes, "paragraph" and "one".  Your CSS properly selects elements that have both of those classes:

```
.paragraph.one { color: red; }
```

This is a useful technique for splitting out facets of the element into separate classes that can be combined individually.  Note also that `<p class="one paragraph">` will match the same selector.

Answer (score 14):

You can't have spaces in `id` values or class names. When you have spaces in the value of the `class` attribute it specifies multiple classes that apply to that element:

```
<p class="paragraph one"> <!--Has both "paragraph" and "one" class-->
```

As for `id` values, the rules (HTML4) state the following:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

As you can see, spaces are not valid. The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) is more leniant, but spaces are still not allowed (emphasis added):

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. **The value must not contain
>   any space characters**.

Answer (score 8):

Modern browsers actually support `id` with spaces.  So on Chrome 54 this works:

```
p#para\ one {
}
```

And modern browsers do not support the `[id="..."]` syntax, so

```
p[id='para one'] {
}
```

does not work in Chrome 54.

Comment: I'm using Robot Framework, so needed double backslash: `${firstNameId}    css=#first\\ name`

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't have spaces. If you use a space it means you're using two different classes. One is `para` and the other one is `one`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a good trick to understand, how some selectors should look like.

1. Open DevTools of the chrome browser (Ctrl + Shift + I)
2. Go to "Elements" Tab
3. Find there that html `p` element and select it
4. Now, on this "Elements" Tab you can find another subset of tabs ("Styles", "Computed", "Layout" etc.). Select "Styles" tab if it's not selected yet
5. In a toolbar right beneath the tab caption there are a filter input and buttons ":hov", ".cls" and "+". Use this "+"-button and you should see a new css-rule is created for you with the proper selector already set for you.

In my case I needed selector for spaced id, because spaced class selectors are good explained (i.g. on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)). So it has created this css-selector:

```css
p#para\ one {
  //...
}
```

This solution was already mentioned in comment for one of the answers, but without DevTools trick