# input with id name id-Output Url fails to select

Tags: css

i have input called it-Output Url

```
<input id="id-Output Url"
```

i cannot select this with css
tried

```
input[id='id-Output Url']{
    font-weight: bold!important;
    }
input#id-Output.Url{
    font-weight: bold!important;
    }
```

none of these seem to work and actually select this id

Comment: An attribute selector should work fine, despite the invalid id https://jsfiddle.net/xq48s3tk/. Technically, you could also escape the space: https://jsfiddle.net/xq48s3tk/1/

Comment: @Turnip Nice catch!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [handling css id and classes with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285451/handling-css-id-and-classes-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use classes instead of ids or you can remove the space and select the element the usual way.
You specify classes in css with `.` and you can chain them together when they are separated by spaces.

Simply modify:

Solution 1

```
<input class="id-Output Url" ...
input.id-Output.Url { ....
```

Solution 2

```
<input id="id-Output-Url" ...
input#id-Output-Url { ....
```

Comment: i only have one id with this name

Comment: They are not @HenryLeBerre . Actually it is a valid id. But is usually not a good ideea to use this format :)

Comment: It is not supported by all browsers but it can be done

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please search your question before posting. You can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285451/handling-css-id-and-classes-with-spaces)

Secondly next time you ask a question, if you cannot find it while you search it, would be great if you would try to create at least a working example (using code sample).

In the third row, you should really take in consideration if using !important is a good ideea. You can read more about this topic [here](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

Also would be better if you use more classes and less id's while working with css. id's should be used only when you are really sure you want some code something only on a single element from all your code.

Avoiding using spaces in your id's and classes would also be a great ideea so you avoid this kind of problems in the future.

Edit: here is a working example of your example since you said that is not working :)

```css
input#id-Output\ Url{
    font-weight: bold!important;
    }
```

```html
<input id="id-Output Url" />
```

Comment: I updated my response. From what I can see is working. So this is why I said you need a working example first of all so we can see more clear what is actually not working :)